# API Gateway w/mTLS and Authorizer - inconsistent $context.identity.sourceIp

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

For a solution with the following AWS architecture:

```
Client A --> API Gateway A --> Server A
                  |
                  |--> Lambda Authorizer (custom and shared)
                  |
Client B --> API Gateway B --> Server B
                  |
              S3 Bucket
              (trustore)
```

Where, in order to consume the API Gateway exposed APIs:

- Both Client IPs need to be whitelisted
- Both Clients need to have valid credentials/token
- Client B requires mTLS (uses API Gateway B)

The AWS API Gateway type used is HTTP API (v2) - mainly because of the cost-effective REST APIs.

The created custom Lambda Authorizer is shared by both API Gateways and is authorizing the Clients based on their:

- IPs - CIDR block validation
- Credentials/Token - authentication

The security configuration for both API Gateways (A and B) is:

```
  securitySchemes:
    oauth:
      in: header
      name: IpAuthorizer
      type: apiKey
      x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: oauth2
      x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
        type: request
        authorizerPayloadFormatVersion: 1.0
        identitySource: "$request.header.Authorization,$context.identity.sourceIp"
        authorizerUri: !Sub: "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaAuthorizerArn}/invocations"
```

But the Lambda Authorizer Events content are different and inconsistent:

- For Client A - from API Gateway A:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "REQUEST",
    "identitySource": "<Token_ClientA>, <IP_ClientA>",
    "headers": {
        "x-forwarded-for": "<IP_ClientA>",
        ...
    },
    "requestContext": {
        "identity": {
            "sourceIp": " <IP_ClientA>",
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

---

**Question 1:**
Why the `$context.identity.sourceIp` part in the `$.identitySource` and the `$.requestContext.identity.sourceIp` are being preceded by an additional whitespace (' ')?

---

- For Client B - from API Gateway B:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "REQUEST",
    "identitySource": "<Token_ClientB>,10.1.9.160:35840",
    "headers": {
        "x-forwarded-for": "<IP_ClientB>",
        ...
    },
    "requestContext": {
        "identity": {
            "sourceIp": "10.1.9.160:35840",
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

---

**Question 2:**
Why the Client IP (`$context.identity.sourceIp`) is not present in neither `$.identitySource` nor `$.requestContext.identity.sourceIp`?

---

**Question 3:**
What is the `10.1.9.160:35840` (not constant) and where does it come from?

---

The only consistency in the Lambda Authorizer Events content seems to be the presence of the `X-Forwarded-For` header, containing the source IP address of the immediate TCP API Gateway connection.

But even the `X-Forwarded-For` header usage is not really consistent, because if we place both Clients behind the same reverse proxy with `X-Forwarded-*` settings enabled, we have different contents for the header in the Lambda Authorizer Events content:

- For Client A - from API Gateway A:

```
{
    ...
    "headers": {
        "x-forwarded-for": "<IP_ClientA>, <IP_ReverseProxy>",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

- For Client B - from API Gateway B:

```
{
    ...
    "headers": {
        "x-forwarded-for": "<IP_ReverseProxy>",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

---

**Question 4:**
Why is the `X-Forwarded-For` header not being correctly passed through API Gateway B?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### After some interactions with AWS Support:

---

**Answer to Questions 1:** (Simple API Gateway)

> We can confirm that there is an existing discrepancy within HTTP API where $.requestContext.identity.sourceIp is with an additional whitespace, and it is with all IPs. We are aware of this issue and we are working on fix it.

**Resolved** - The fix was already applied and the issue is no longer reproducible.

---

**Answer to Questions 2, 3 and 4:** (API Gateway with mTLS)

> The backend team has identified multiple discrepancies with the IP addresses, and they are working on fixing the issue. The issue is being work-on timelessly by the API Gateway service team, and they have implemented the pipeline to deploy the fix. However, there's no exact ETA of when the issue might be fixed.

**Not yet solved**

**Conclusion:**

- Not possible to validate the Client IP (`$context.identity.sourceIp`) using `$.identitySource` or `$.requestContext.identity.sourceIp`
- Not possible to validate the real Client IP if it is behind a reverse proxy
- Only possible to validate the nearest/last/only IP present in the `X-Forwarded-For` header

---